# Handling collection changes in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We're rolling out our own mutable collection class to use within a React list component. Since the actual contents to be rendered are managed separately by that collection (which we inject in the component via `props`), we're faced with two design doubts:

- whether the collection object should be held in the `state` or, instead, kept in the `props` or an instance property of the component (given it can handle its own state);
- what a good idiom for triggering rendering on collection changes would be.

We've been brainstorming the best way to do this. Currently the collection's mutation methods return a promise which resolves with the collection itself; if we keep the collection in `state`, is it a good idea to `done()` the promise with something like (in CoffeeScript)?

```
@state.collection_object.add_an_item('foo').done(
  (mutated_collection_object) => @setState(collection_object: mutated_collection_object)
)
```

I'd like to get some insight on which approaches to this you've taken/seen so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Holding a collection in the state can get messy pretty quickly, with props I feel it's even worse. Have you considered the holding the collection outside the component entirely? I've gone that route.

You can trigger synthetic events upon change with something like Node's EventEmitter, then listen for changes from within the component in order to trigger the re-render. Plus you can move code out of the component that more specifically deals with the collection itself.

I found this simple example, hopefully it's of some help. Good luck!

http://mwdesilva.com/posts/event-driven-react-js-components-via-an-event-emitter-mixin